# ASP.NET MVC4 Entity Framework, will not generate database, saying ID fields are required?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have built a couple MVC3 sites now, and thought I would give MVC4 a stab.  But I'm not getting very far and am unsure why...

Using code first to write my models and have the database generated.  However, it's not working and throwing a validation error telling me the ID field is required.  I followed their naming conventions, even tried a few different ones as shown in different tutorials, and nothing seems to work.  In the past, EF has been able to determine my PKs and kept me from having to worry about specifying them for inserts.  This appears to be the case in all the MVC4 tutorials I'm looking at, but somehow even when I follow them exactly, my database will not generate.

Truncated example of my User model:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then, my initializer that is causing the error:

```
    public class WorkoutInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<WorkoutContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(WorkoutContext context) {

        var users = new List<User>
        {
            new User {
                FirstName = "D",
                LastName = "H",
                Email = "blah@blahblah.com",
                Password = "3f9cbbb2dad0774468af842678b11dafa7a16d81",

            },
        };
        users.ForEach(u => context.Users.Add(u));
        context.SaveChanges();

        ...bunch more stuff...
    }
}
```

The program throws a ValidationError when context.SaveChanges() is called, informing me that "The UserId field is required."

What am I missing here?

Comment: are you sure your UserId is of string type ?

Comment: Have you tried naming the UserId just 'Id'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though EF has not created UserId as the primary key and as an identity column when generating the database. This error is being thrown because the UserId is a non-nullable int and cant be left null. You could manually change the SQL Server column to Identity to Yes in the column properties in SSMS but I think it would just be easier to decorate UserId with the [Key] attribute to force it to be the primary key on database generation:

```
[Key]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Note that this requires the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, though I never really figured it out.  Had to create a new project and copy all my files over, and it worked fine.  Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

UserId should probably be an int or a Guid shouldn't it?